# Screen reader i.e. JAWS doesn't read text of a button when text is changed on click of that button?

Tags: jquery, accessibility, wai-aria, uiaccessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I am facing one minor difficulty while making my software ARIA accessibility enabled. Any kind of help would be appreciated!

I have a div which works as a 'Edit' button with click event using jQuery. I am changing text of that button 'Save' on click event. Screen reader like JAWS reads "Edit button" when the focus comes to that button for the first time.

But I want JAWS to recognise the change happened after click event i.e. After click JAWS should read "Save button". Any help? (Note that even after click, focus stays on the same button)

HTML code for that div/button:

```
<div role="button" class="js-btn" aria-label="Edit">Edit</div>
```

jQuery code to handle click event:

```
$(document).on("click",".js-btn",function(e){
    $(this).innerHTML("Save");
    $(this).attr("aria-label","Save");
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will specifically fix the issue, but please, use `button` for buttons! Browsers and assistive tech attach all kinds of native behaviors and styles based on semantics, and while you can kind of simulate it with aria, that should be an absolute last resort. `<button class="js-btn">Edit</button>`. No aria-label or role needed.

Comment: try adding aria-live="polite"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (Note that even after click, focus stays on the same button)

If it's your expected behaviour, this is the answer to your question : as long as the focus stays on the element the screenreader won't re-read its data.

Use two buttons, show the "Save" button after clicking on "Edit" and hide the "edit" button.

```
<button id="edit">Edit</div>
<button id="save" class="hidden">Save</div>

$("#edit").on("click", function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $("#save").removeClass("hidden").focus();
});
```

Comment: I decided to go with two different buttons and changing the visibility and focus and it worked! thanks

Answer (score 4):

First: props for thinking of accessibility, and testing for it! But `aria` and its features are really meant to extend html for interactive things it can't natively handle. And html can totally handle a button. So use `button` here, please, and you can skip the `role` and `aria-label`.

Having the native semantics might be enough to make JAWS notice the change in text - not sure, but worth a try. If it doesn't, you could add `aria-live="polite"` or `aria-live="assertive"` to your `button` and that should cue the SR to announce when its contents change. (Which one to use depends on how pushy you want to be about informing your user - `polite` won't interrupt whatever they're doing, `assertive` will.)

`<button aria-live="polite" class="js-btn">Edit</button>`